# jQuery add more input maxLimit not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this Code for add more input using jQuery:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var MaxInputs = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

    var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text box added

    $(AddButton).click(function (e) //on add input button click
    {
        if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><input type="text" name="mytext1[]" id="field" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        if (x > 1) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
        return false;
    })

});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info">Add More Field</a>

<div id="InputsWrapper">
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="mytext1[]" id="field" value="Text 1"><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a>
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="mytext1[]" id="field" value="Text 1"><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a>
        </div>

</div>
```

in default i add two input and set 8 input for MaxInput ans set 1 for keep input.

Now, I have Two Problem:

1- i cant remove One of these two default input.

2- Maxinput not work with `+1 default input`. my mean when we set `1` keep input, if add One default Max input This not work and add `8 input` + `1 defualt` + `1 keep input`. with this we have `10 input`. this is false. we need to add `9 input`.

How do can can i fix this problems?

Live Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5UCex/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UCex/11/)

1. Correct selector to calculate length - `$("#InputsWrapper input");`.
2. `var AddButton = "#AddMoreFileBox";` and not `var AddButton = $("#AddMoreFileBox");`
3. You have to check length of input inside every **Add** event.
4. To have Atmost 8 inputs - `if (x < MaxInputs)` instead of `if (x <= MaxInputs)`

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var MaxInputs = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper input"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton = "#AddMoreFileBox"; //Add button ID

    var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text box added

    $(AddButton).click(function (e) //on add input button click
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper input");
        x = InputsWrapper.length;
        if (x < MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).parents('#InputsWrapper').append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext1[]" id="field" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function (e) { //user click on remove text

        if (x > 1) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
        return false;
    })

});
```

Comment: this one not allow to add more field when others completly deleted

Comment: @shaunakde: this worked. But I add any class for remove `div` But your Code not worked. See Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5UCex/13/

Comment: when you change a class , you have to change jQuery selector. Check this - Its working http://jsfiddle.net/5UCex/14/

Answer (score 1):

also got a working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/5UCex/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var MaxInputs = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

    var x = InputsWrapper.length +1; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount = 2; //to keep track of text box added

    AddButton.click(function (e) //on add input button click
    {
        if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            InputsWrapper.append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext1[]" id="field" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        if (x > 0) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            FieldCount --; //decrement FieldCount
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
        return false;
    })

});
```

main changes were :

-decrement fieldCount when removing

-Set initial FieldCount to correct amount of initial fields

-Fixed issue with zeroBasedIndex

Comment: Please delete your old post :)

Comment: @IshanJain if you tell me how to, i can just "undelete" but my new Answer works like a charme, doesnt it ?

Comment: @johnSmith: your Code Worked But Not work to keep track of text box added.

Answer (score 0):

working code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var MaxInputs = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

    var x = InputsWrapper.find('div').length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text box added

    $(AddButton).click(function (e) //on add input button click
    {
        if (x < MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext1[]" id="field" value="Text ' + FieldCount + '"/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        if (x >= 1) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
        return false;
    })

});
```

changed lines:

```
var x = InputsWrapper.find('div').length; //initlal text box count
```

and here

```
    $("body").on("click", ".removeclass", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        if (x >= 1) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
        return false;
    })
```